# TypeScript class A's method to work as a pass-through to a B's method

Tags: javascript, typescript, composition, function-composition

I am trying to wrap a third-party library auth0-js into my own class. In the example below an `Authentication` class from Auth0.js is being wrapped and is used as the implementation for the pass-through methods. See how `buildLogoutUrl(options)` does nothing more than invoking a function on the wrapped object.

**Is there a more concise way to "redirect" Authentication's buildLogoutUrl(...) to `wa`'s buildLogoutUrl(...) *without using inheritance*?**

```
import * as a0 from "auth0-js";

export class Authentication {

  constructor(private wa: a0.Authentication) { }

  buildLogoutUrl(options?: a0.LogoutOptions | undefined): string {
    return this.wa.buildLogoutUrl(options);
  }

  // Many other methods...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the expensive of flexibility, you can save yourself a little bit of typing by using an assignment:

```
import * as a0 from "auth0-js";

export class Authentication {

  constructor(private wa: a0.Authentication) { }

  buildLogoutUrl = this.wa.buildLogoutUrl;

}
```

By "flexibility",  I mean that you can't change the function signature or perform any pre-processing on the arguments, for example. Also your class no longer has a fixed public interface that you control (imagine that the author of the library changes the function signature).